# Can I build a route recording app with flutter?

Tags: flutter, dictionary, routes, navigation, journey

I’m hoping to build a map recording app. All I want to know is can I do this with flutter?
Just a typical hiking app that will record my journey and then allow me to keep a record of the trip. With a screenshot.
Would need to record key milestones along the way. I live in the U.K. and I will need the app for both iOS and android. I’m keen to do this in flutter if it’s possible.
Any advice would be appreciated.
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it can be done using the Flutter framework and currently available plugins.

Comment: Thanks. I’m going to get on with it then.

Comment: The devil will of course be in the details, what you actually want your app to be able to do. But that is entirely different questions :)